# Delta rollover status - better to not cross threshold?

Tags: loyalty-programs, delta-air-lines

I'm trying to understand the Delta SkyMiles Rollover policy.

It seems like it would be better to **not get status** in certain situations.

Delta has tiers at 25, 50, 75, and 125k miles.

If I know I'll fly 70,000 miles next year, then I think I'm incentivized to not fly too much this year.

For example, if I fly 49,000 miles this year, then I earn Tier 1 at 25k, and have 24k roll over. When I fly 70k next year, I reach their Tier 3 (75k) status.

On the other hand, if I fly 51,000 miles this year, then I earn Tier 2 at 50k, and have 1k roll over. When I fly 70k next year, I do not reach Tier 3 (75k) status.

Am I missing something about how the rollover works? This seems like a strange incentive structure, especially given the big step from 75k to 125k (most other airlines have their top tier at 100k).

Comment: In one case you get benefits of Tier 1 for one year and Tier 3 the next year. In the other case you get benefits of Tier 2 for both years, so it balances out. Depending on which exact benefits you are interested in (and possibly the timing of the flights), one or the other may be more interesting for you. But can you really know in advance exactly how many miles you are going to fly/earn next year?

Answer (score 1):

You can play this game, but it's more complicated than that, and you have to decide whether it's worth the bother for the somewhat moderate benefits of the program.

Delta bases qualification not only on miles flown but also on dollars spent. For example currently you need to spent $15000/year with them to attain Diamond status. That's likely to go up after the pandemic.

So not only would you have to throttle your flying but also your spending accordingly.

At the moment, I believe you can roll over ALL miles from this year into next, regardless of which status you will reach (Covid benefit). So the most efficient way would be to fly as much as possible this year. Unless, of course, that pushes you under the spend target for next year.